# Is there an electrostatic equivalent material property to magnetic retentivity?

Tags: physics, materials

Consider the following thought experiment:
I take a chunk of some material X which contains atomic dipoles., not free charges, and subject it to an external electric field. We know that the dipoles will align themselves to the field, this is analogous to atomic scale magnetic dipoles in a ferromagnetic aligning themselves to an external magnetic. The question is about what happens when the field is removed.

Is there any material which exhibits some kind of electrical retentivity, i.e. the dipoles do not all rotate back resulting in a remnant electric field?

Comment: Are you talking about electrets?

Comment: see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret

Comment: Useful search term : dielectric relaxation. Often seen in some types of film capacitor and electrolytics. Take the material used in those capacitors and experiment on it. This is a short term effect, unlike electrets which can freeze in a field permanently.